# T4 generated JavaScript constructor from a .Net Type

Tags: javascript, .net, types, t4

Sometimes we may need to generate some javascript constructor in order to apply strong typing/intellisense in JavaScript in a JavaScript developer tool.  Is it possible to generate a JavaScript constructor function from a normal .NET Type using T4?  Is there any utility class could do this?  Thanks!

Comment: I was found that there is a good article talked about this with a good sample T4 source code. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/578827/Generate-Knockout-Viewmodels-using-T4-templates

Answer (score 0):

There's no utility class, and if your types are in a different assembly than your `T4` would make it easier.

You would have to use `System.Reflection` or `EnvDte` in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Although the following doesn't use T4 directly, it may interest you. We had similar requirements and ended up writing a library for generating Javascript classes from .NET types. You can reference it in a T4 file, expose it as a web server method, or just use it as a command line tool.

It's available as a [nuget package - ClosureExterns.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosureExterns.NET/). The code and [more info is on github](https://github.com/bdb-opensource/closure-externs-dotnet).